# Cakephp Translate missing table

Tags: php, cakephp, translate

I'm trying to retrieve translated data in CakePHP but I'm having some issues.

My model is like follows.

```
class Newelement extends AppModel{
    public $name = "Newelement";

    public $actsAs = array(
        'Translate' => array(
            'title' => 'titleTranslation',
            'subtitle' => 'subtitleTranslation',
            'content' => 'contentTranslation'
        )
    );

    // Use a different model (and table)
    public $translateModel = 'NewElementTranslation';
    // Use a different table for translateModel
    public $translateTable = 'newelement_translations';
}
```

And my model for translations is this:

```
class NewelementTranslation extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'field'; // important
}
```

I can save data with different locales. The data is properly saved in the database.

But when I'm trying to retrieve data using the "find" method...

```
$newelements = $this->Newelement->find();
print_r($newelements);
```

I get the following error:

```
Missing Database Table
Error: Table new_element_translations for model titleTranslation was not found in datasource default.
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_table.ctp
Stack Trace

CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 3476 → Model->setSource(string)
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 1063 → Model->getDataSource()
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 2880 → DboSource->read(Newelement, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 2852 → Model->_readDataSource(string, array)
APP/Controller/NewelementsController.php line 39 → Model->find()
[internal function] → NewelementsController->index()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(NewelementsController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 187 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(NewelementsController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 110 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

This doesn't happen if I use the default i18n database, using this code for my model and avoiding the use of the translated model.

```
class Newelement extends AppModel{
    public $name = "Newelement";

    public $actsAs = array(
        'Translate' => array(
            'title' => 'titleTranslation',
            'subtitle' => 'subtitleTranslation',
            'content' => 'contentTranslation'
        )
    );
}
```

I want to use the translateModel and translateTable to maintain the databases easily, because this won't be the only Model that I want to translate.

If someone could help me it would be great because I'm stuck with this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but try sticking with capitalization standards - your model should be `NewElement`, not `Newelement`...etc

Comment: Thanks! I had a mistake with one of the model classes as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some naming convention problems no doubt as Dave stated.  I'd recommend changing to NewElement and the corresponding table would be new_elements ... then on your translations I'd do the following:

```
// Use a different model (and table)
public $translateModel = 'NewElementTranslation'; 
// uses the new_element_translations table if no model file is written by default.
```